# What is an equivalent of single_cat_title for getting the slug of the category?

Tags: php, categories, archives, slug

I searched for something like `single_cat_slug` but I did not find something relevant. All I don't know how to do it is to find the slug, not the name, of the currently opened category page. I do not know how to find the slug if I have the name.

```php
<?php 
$c = is_category();
$d = !empty(get_the_category());

$cat = $c ? single_cat_title('', false) :
    ( $d ? get_the_category()[0]->slug : NULL );

if ($cat !== NULL) {

?>
```

and after this there is some HTML in which I will use $cat to highlight the currently opened category (either a post in that category or a category archive page itself).

The issue in my case is that `single_cat_title` does not return the slug but the title (the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a category archive page, you can use [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to get the data of the current category in the main request, and get the slug like so: `get_queried_object()->slug`.